# find a string from line and from 3 different choices and print

Tags: c++

I have just started to program an I am stuck in one problem. So I have a txt file that contains a single line:
i.e.

> 1234567890123 1234567890123 sam WELCOME chris
>
> 1234567890123 1234567890123 chris WELCOME sam
>
> 1234567890123 1234567890123 luke WELCOME sam

so the text could be either of 3 above lines.

so i first need to scan for first occuring letter from either sam chris or luke
and return that letter.

I have decided to have seperate function for this.
so far I have done:

```
string isWanted(string & line1)
{

if (line1.find_first_of("sam"))
{ 
    line1 = ("sam");
}
else if (line1.find_first_of("luke"))
{
    line1 = ("luke");
}
else if (line1.find_first_of("chris"))
{
    line1= ("chris");
}
return line1;
}
```

For out put I only get sam although its different letter.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [the help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Welcome to SO.

Comment: [`std::string::find_first_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of) does _not_ return a boolean, it returns a position. If the string is not found, it returns the highest possible unsigned value (since it is defined as -1, but that overflows in unsigned variables).